# Push EventBus Primefaces is not working

Tags: primefaces, push

This example of Push notifications in primefaces is not working. The message is not showing

**The view:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/main_template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="bodyContent">
        <p:growl widgetVar="growl" showDetail="true" />
        <h:form>
            <p:panel header="Growl">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel for="summary" value="Summary: " />
                    <p:inputText id="summary" value="#{growlBean.summary}"
                        required="true" />
                    <p:outputLabel for="detail" value="Detail: " />
                    <p:inputText id="detail" value="#{growlBean.detail}"
                        required="true" />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton value="Send" actionListener="#{growlBean.send}" />
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

    <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/notify" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleMessage(facesmessage) {
            facesmessage.severity = 'info';

            PF('growl').show([facesmessage]);
        }
    </script>
</ui:composition>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Backing bean:**

```
package co.com.test.primefacespush.managedbean;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import org.primefaces.push.EventBus;
import org.primefaces.push.EventBusFactory;

@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class GrowlBean {

    private final static String CHANNEL = "/notify";

    private String text, summary, detail;

    public void send() {
        EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
        eventBus.publish(CHANNEL, new FacesMessage(summary, detail));
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(String detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }
}
```

**PushEndpoint:**

```
package co.com.test.primefacespush.managedbean;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import org.primefaces.push.annotation.OnMessage;
import org.primefaces.push.annotation.PushEndpoint;
import org.primefaces.push.impl.JSONEncoder;

@PushEndpoint("/notify")
public class NotifyResource {

    @OnMessage(encoders = { JSONEncoder.class })
    public FacesMessage onMessage(FacesMessage message) {
        return message;
    }
}
```

What is wrong? I can't see it. I have no errors in the JBoss console neither in the browser console

**Frameworks:**

```
Shiro 1.2.3
Mojarra 2.1.7
Primefaces 5.1
JDK 1.7
JBoss 7.1.1
```

Comment: channel should be channel="/notify" instead of channel="notify". You missed the / in the view

Comment: You are right it was me doing a test, with the / doesn't work too

Comment: set a breakpoint in the onMessage method in your endpoint, in addition open the developer tools of the browser of your choice. Is the breakpoint reached? Do the developer tools show some js errors?

Comment: The breakpoint is not reached, browsers don't show errors

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a late response.
How do you deploy your application on JBoss?
We had an issue where our war file that was deployed on Tomcat had a .jar dependency with code for PUSH functionality.
We noticed similar issues, onMessage not invoking at all no matter what we tried.

After a few days of lead GUI architect's investigation we have discovered that atmosphere developers included a bug (they are loading .class files annotated with @Pushendpoint with getResource() instead of getResourceAsStream() so classloader cannot find it obviously.

The solution for us was to overlay the jar .class fiels with maven and manually copy them into war files (move push endpoint generated .class files from .jar folder to war generated .class files folder). Any results with that?

Comment: We deploy the war in JBoss, we only use Jboss without another web server

Comment: @JohnB I might not have worded my question properly, the real question is, whether or not you deploy application with your PUSH endpoint classes as a war dependency (code is in .jar file in lib/ folder). If yes, then this fix might apply in your situation.

Comment: Could you show me the structure of the directories through an image? Please

Comment: [Default .war structure/no overlay](http://i.imgur.com/EAiK0W1.png) [with overlay/bug fix](http://i.imgur.com/rT4eeau.png) Sorry about the blurred stuff, NDA and such...